# android scrollbarTrackVertical scrollbarThumbVertical doesn't work for dialog

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-scrollbar

I modified my theme using the following style (part):

```
<item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_1</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_2</item>
```

(plus of course drawable definition).

However it only works with activity. When activity opens dialog (DialogFragment), scrollbars are standard ones, not mine. Why?

Any help?